# How do you insert a String into the first empty cell in the first available column, i.e. C1, F1, AA1

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub-routine that searches for the first available cell in the first column that is empty. I would like to insert a String into this cell.

What's the best way to do this? I have tried like this:

```
Range(NextEmptyCol).Value = "New Query"
```

Here is my sub-routine:

```
Sub CreateNewQuery()

Dim NextEmptyCol As Long

Sheets("DataFeedSheet").Activate

NextEmptyCol = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column + 1

'    MsgBox "Column number " & NextEmptyCol & vbCr & _
'           "Or column letter """ & Replace(Cells(1, NextEmptyCol).Address(0, 0), 1, "") & """", _
'           vbInformation, "The Next Empty Column is..."

Range(NextEmptyCol).Value = "New Query"

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `Range("A" & NextEmptyCol).Value = "New Query"`?

Comment: Hmmm that seems to insert the String into cell A80 for some reason... in my spreadsheet the next available cell in the first column that is empty is CB1

Comment: Column `CB` is the first column in your sheet? Maybe you and I have a different understanding of *first column*? Could you please elaborate what this term means to you? I had expect it to be column `A`.

Comment: So the first column where cell 1 is empty, sorry if my question was ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
Sub CreateNewQuery()

Dim NextEmptyCol As Long

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

NextEmptyCol = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Column + 1

'    MsgBox "Column number " & NextEmptyCol & vbCr & _
'           "Or column letter """ & Replace(Cells(1, NextEmptyCol).Address(0, 0), 1, "") & """", _
'           vbInformation, "The Next Empty Column is..."

Cells(1, NextEmptyCol).Value = "New Query"

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Could you explain the (1, NextEmtpyCol) for me?

Comment: Cells(row_number, column_number). In this case it is 1st row and whatever number is assigned to NextEmptyCol variable. You can find more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx)

Comment: If you use `Range()` then you have to pass the column as a character. If you use `Cells()` then you have the option to pass the column as a number (so column `D` = column 4). Hence, I used `Cells()` instead of `Range()` because `Find()` is giving us the *next available column* as a number.